# Can both appmenu-qt and appmenu-qt:i386 be installed at the same time?

Tags: unity, 64-bit, qt, appmenu

OK, so here's the backstory.

Skype recently released version 4.3 on Ubuntu. It now has a menu bar, which it did not before. The only issue is that because it is 32-bit software, it's menu bar is not integrated into the unity menu bar, but instead is in the window itself.

This is solved by installing `appmenu-qt:i386` , which I assume makes it work because it's now the 32-bit version of the `appmenu-qt` library.

The problem is that in installing `appmenu-qt:i386` `apt` removes `appmenu-qt:amd64`, which means that the 32-bit and 64-bit libraries seemingly cannot be installed at the same time.

This is a problem as having `appmenu-qt:i386` installed only breaks 64-bit QT software appmenu integration.

Is there some way to fix this problem? Perhaps by having both libraries installed at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and here is how I got it solved. Most probably it's not the best solution and you found a solution yourself but I'll post it anyways.

First I installed the 64 bit package and downloaded the i386 manually from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386/appmenu-qt).

Then I opened the file with file-roler and extracted the /usr and copied it over. Now VirtualBox and Skype are both using global menu.

Comment: Alright, this worked! Definitely not the most beautiful solution though, so I'll accept it if there are no other answers in the next little while.

Comment: To newly arriving users: on Vivid it is possible to install both with Apt, and solves the original issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: supposedly this was fixed but in the version they say it was fixed in the problem still seems to exist